# Match a struct using reference

Tags: rust, match

To match a struct while preventing a move, I want to use a reference to do the match. So the following code will do the job:

```
struct Foo(i32);

fn main() {
    let x = Foo(1);
    match &x {
        ref a => println!("hello"),
    }
    println!("{}", x.0);
}
```

But I am surprised to find that the following code also works, which actually matched a struct (`x`) with a reference (`ref a`). But, shouldn't it be a type mismatch here?

```
struct Foo(i32);

fn main() {
    let x = Foo(1);
    match x {
        ref a => println!("hello")
    }
    println!("{}", x.0);
}
```

Comment: `ref` means "taking a reference of". It is not a type.

Comment: See this blog post http://xion.io/post/code/rust-patterns-ref.html. There is all you need to know about `ref` and `&`.

Comment: Thanks, that are very helpful!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ref` is not a normal part of the pattern that "strips away" something from the value, but is a modifier of the name binding, like `mut`. It instructs the name to bind to a reference to the value instead of the value directly.

Let's see what type `a` has in each case:

```
match &x {
    ref a => {
        let () = a;
    }
}
match x {
    ref b => {
        let () = b;
    }
}
```

The `let () = a;` is a trick to find out the type of `a`. And indeed the compiler tells us:

```
   |
7  |             let () = a;
   |                 ^^ expected &&Foo, found ()

[...]
   |
12 |             let () = b;
   |                 ^^ expected &Foo, found ()
```

So in the first case, we have reference to a reference, namely `&&Foo`. This is because we're matching on the expression `&x` (type: `&Foo`) and then tell the compiler to bind the name "by reference".